# Results not matching when running session multiple times

Tags: tensorflow, keras

When i tried to print  out1 and out2 i observed that the values coming in out2 doesnt exist in out1. But out2 is just finding the maximum from out1. Need help

```
import tensorflow as tf
from keras import backend as K
box_class_probs = tf.random_normal([2, 2, 1, 2], mean=1, stddev=4, seed = 1)
max_ind_class=K.max(box_class_probs,axis=-1)

with tf.Session() as sess:
    out1=sess.run(box_class_probs)
    print(out1)
    out2=sess.run(max_ind_class)
    print(out2)
```

output:

```
[[[[-2.24527287  6.93839502]]

  [[ 1.26131749 -8.77081585]]]


 [[[ 1.39699364  3.36489725]]

  [[ 3.37129188 -7.49171829]]]]
---------------------------------------------
---------------------------------------------
---------------------------------------------
[[[ 1.96837616]
  [ 3.06311464]]

 [[ 9.33515644]
  [ 6.58941841]]]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to run both of your results in one session run, because you are generating the box_class_probs randomly, and according to the random seed (default or internal), it is going to change every time you execute a session run. And also, keep in mind its always more consistent to get the current keras backend session using [K.get_session()](https://keras.io/backend/) and then run your code when you are mixing keras and tensorflow.

```
sess = K.get_session()
out1, out2 = sess.run([box_class_probs, max_ind_class])
print(out1)
print(out2)
```

Result:

```
[[[[-2.2452729  6.938395 ]]

  [[ 1.2613175 -8.770817 ]]]


 [[[ 1.3969936  3.3648973]]

  [[ 3.3712919 -7.4917183]]]]
[[[6.938395 ]
  [1.2613175]]

 [[3.3648973]
  [3.3712919]]]
```